# How to hide JBTextField placeholder when user starts typing

Tags: java, textfield, intellij-plugin

I'm new to plugin development for IntelliJ.

I'm using `JBTextField` as a text input so I can set the placeholder text using `JBTextField.getEmptyText().setText(...)` method.

But according to the [IntelliJ Platform UI Guidelines](https://jetbrains.design/intellij/controls/input_field/) it says:

> Hide the placeholder when the user starts typing, not when the input field gets the focus.

which is not the way that the textfield itself does. It hides the placeholder when it gets focus.

The question is, how can I change this behavior so that the placeholder disappears when the user type something (For example something like the native IDE's "New Class" popup window).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution based on this [answer](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/4862614237202-How-to-hide-JBTextField-placeholder-when-user-starts-typing?page=1#community_comment_4874919264274) by Yann Cebron.

> The default behavior from `com.intellij.ui.components.TextComponentEmptyText#isStatusVisible` can be customized via `JBTextField.STATUS_VISIBLE_FUNCTION`  property which is a reference to a `BooleanFunction<JTextComponent>`.

So we can reference a boolean function to the `STATUS_VISIBLE_FUNCTION` key like this:

```
import com.intellij.ui.components.JBTextField;
import com.intellij.ui.components.TextComponentEmptyText;
import com.intellij.util.BooleanFunction;

textField = new JBTextField();
textField.getEmptyText().setText("Placeholder...");
textField.putClientProperty(
    TextComponentEmptyText.STATUS_VISIBLE_FUNCTION, 
    (BooleanFunction<JBTextField>) tf -> tf.getText().isEmpty()
);
```